# find client's location with the java code and not using jquery or java script

Tags: java, jar, google-api, location, ip

I want to find client's  location with java code and not using jquery or java script. can someone help me to write this code? I haven't found any information about this.
please suggest me to write code in java to find client's location ...

Comment: Slow down. What do you want to do? Are you making a website that uses javascript, or are you making another type of application? What is the relevance of jquery/javascript in this question?

Comment: Read [ask] before asking a question

Comment: I am working on to make a jar file to find location of client and by implementing the jar user can see the location of client. I want to implement pure java class without using jquery and java script. so it can use it in other class by just implementing jar file

Comment: Unfortunately SO is not a code writing service. Please consider taking the [tour] and having a look at [ask]. You may also want to visit the [Help]

Comment: Are you talking about a physical location, like latitude and longitude coordinates?

Answer (score -1):

```
public String getRemoteHost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request){
String ip = request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for");
if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)){
    ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
}
if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)){
    ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
}
if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)){
    ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
return ip.equals("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1")?"127.0.0.1":ip;
```

}

Comment: This is servlet-specific. OP didn't specify if he uses servlets.